# MySQL SELECT against varbinary column

Tags: mysql, binary

This is a follow up to a previous issue I had posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486025/alternative-to-hashed-ssn-as-a-key-in-mysql).

I created a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_test_table` (
    `record_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `col1` BINARY(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `col2` CHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`record_id`)
)
```

Then ran the statement:

```
INSERT INTO my_test_table (col1, col2) VALUES(sha1('test'), sha1('test') );
```

The data looks like...

1     0x6139346138666535636362313962613631633463    a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3

I'm not sure how I can select against the VARBINARY column. I can select against the CHAR like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_test_table WHERE col2 = sha1('test');
```

I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM my_test_table WHERE col1 = hex(sha1('test'));
```

And other variations but can't seem to find a solution (if there is one). I need to be able to check to see if a value already exists in the database before I allow a new insert. I was looking at VARBINARY and BINARY based on previous suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Why is the column of type binary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not read your previous question, but based on the source code in this question, you are only storing the first 20 characters of the sha1 hash in col1, so if you want to select it you should just look for the first 20 characters of the sha1 hash.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_test_table 
WHERE col1 = left(sha1('test'),20);
```

Comment: That worked. I was confused as to why it's visible in my MySQL editor as "0x6139346138666535636362313962613631633463". Is there any reason I should fear the first 20 being any less random than the 40 CHAR string?

Comment: Certainly the chance of a collision is substantially higher using 20 characters compared to 40. You should do some research on hash collisions and decide which hash function is right for you.

Comment: Thanks. I was just confused since other recommendations were to store the hashed value as binary, but if this limits it's uniqueness when doing a compare, I think CHAR may be better. Appreciate the help all around.

Comment: Yes, if you stored the hash value as binary you can store it in 20 bytes instead of 40 bytes as a char. The missing piece is that you need to use `UNHEX` to convert the hash value to binary. Like this: `INSERT INTO my_test_table (col1, col2) VALUES(unhex(sha1('test')), sha1('test') );`, and then you can select the dat alike this: `SELECT * FROM my_test_table WHERE col1 = unhex(sha1('test'));`

Answer (score 0):

```
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'col1' at row 1: INSERT INTO my_test_table (col1, col2) VALUES(sha1('test'), sha1('test') )
```

Can this be the reason why you cannot select the data properly?

Comment: May be an error in the source I copied. I was able to insert ok and can see the results in my table after a SELECT *

Comment: Well, I was trying to help on what you gave to me. It is not my duty to try to guess what you meant when it is clearly not working. Next time, try your best posting the working code :)

Comment: Sorry. Didn't mean to be short in my reply. I appreciate your attempt to help and agree that it's garbage in - garbage out. The first reply was enough to get me in the right direction, so I worked with that. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

BTW the `sha1('test')` returns a STRING of hex characters...

You should use `unhex(sha1('test'))` when inputing data as a hex string, or else it wont be entered as acsii values which wont work with matching at all

`SELECT * FROM my_test_table WHERE col1 = unhex(sha1('test'));`
should be the matching query also.